# Why Firebase show negative crash free user for my app

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

[image]
I have an Android app which has Firebase Crashlytics enabled, I updated my app this morning (12 hours ago) and on Firebase app status is need investigation and crash free user are in negative number -9.06%. when i check Crashlytics it has only 3 crashes among 10% active users, this app has 600K users all together. On playstore it also has the same 3 crashes.

I checked on play store it looks all okay.

Firebase crashlytics image says only 5 events (crash there)
[image]

if i check crash reports of all version, there is no such things , almost 15,16 crashes altogether
screen shot
[image]

Comment: This could be a bug. Do you get the same behavior if you open the Crashlytics dashboard using an incognito tab? Could you share a screenshot?

Comment: @Gerardo i added screenshot . now release repots says -35% crash free user (which does not make sense ).
 Firebase crashlytics says only 5 event (crashes) there. Between playstore also reports same 5 crash for 5 users

Comment: Does the version 3.1.3 have different builds? The Crash Free Users (CFU) stats take only the "version" so if there are different builds for that version, the CFU will ignore the build part and show the info for all the build related to 3.1.3. If you include all the builds in the filter, does the data make more sense?

Comment: if i remove filter and check all crashes in last 24 hours , that events are not same , reports say over all crashes are less than 20 in last 24 hours .
any idea.

Comment: In the CFU card, if you hover over the "?" that is on top of the percentage, what does the tool tip show? The tool tip will show you the data used for calculating the CFU percentage, it would be interesting to see what those values are.